# JQuery accordion menu help

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

this is what i have right now, i want the menu to start up as collapsed, but the "Transaction" tab is always open

```
        <ul id="menu"> 
                            <li><a href=""> New </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Transaction</a>
                            <ul> 
                        <li><a href="http://www.php.net/">add</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/">delete</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="http://java.sun.com/">correct</a></li> 
                        </ul> </li>

                            <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                            </ul>
```

this is my initMenu function:

```
function initMenu() {
    $('#menu ul').hide();
    $('#menu li a').click(
function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
}
);
}
$(document).ready(function() { initMenu(); });
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: first of all, you dont need the function call in the "onload" attribute, as your running the same function (initMenu()) when the document loads in your javascript.

Comment: i followed this example: http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu/index_collapsed.html

Comment: @Mike, when i take out onload it still does not work the way i want to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the 'onload' attribute in the body tag.

Also, you need to change

```
<li> <a href=""> New </a> </li>
```

to

```
    <li> <a href="#"> New </a> </li>
```

Here's a working example for you
http://jsfiddle.net/UVfMx/

Comment: @xrum, you would need to show us the rest of the code then.  It is likely something else in the code that is causing the problem